# Ruby conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, oop, conditional-statements

I have a condition like:

```
if connection
  if "name" == connection.name
    ...
  end
end
```

`connection` may have `nil` value initially, so I am not able to check `if connection && "name" == connection.name`

How can I simplify the condition efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unless connection.nil? || connection.name != "name"
  #...Statements
end
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if connection and connection.name == "name"
   ...
end
```

Comment: Easier to read and understand than the negative version above.